# Chatting Application using Node js(with socket.io)

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am new to Node js,developing a chatting application referring to example given in http://socket.io/get-started/chat/. In this chatting application client(browser) sends requests to the server and gets connected if succeeded. Server code is given below

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
 res.sendfile('chat.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Client code: chat.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Welcome to chat</title>
<script>
 var io = require('socket.io-client');
 var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000', {reconnect: true});
 socket.on('connect', function(socket) { 
        console.log('Connected!');
 });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="messages"></ul>
<form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="on" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I get the message 'listening on *:3000' when I run the application(using eclipse) and point my browser to localhost:3000, I get the chat.html page , however I never get the message 'a user connected'. I mean client here is not connecting to server socket and hence I am not getting the above message displayed in console. I tried everything I can do. Any suggestions will be of great help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `require` on frontend

```
var io = require('socket.io-client');
```

Use

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: any bug in  the inspect element of browser ?